# mat-select value is not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have in a `view` of one of my `Angular Components` a `mat-select`.
This `Angular Component` has a form used to edit some data. So the idea is when I open the component view, the form is prefilled.

```
  <mat-form-field> 
          <mat-select
            [(value)]="selectedGroups"
            placeholder="Select the associated Bitbucket groups ..."
            multiple>

            <mat-option
            *ngFor="let group of bitbucketgroupsList?.results"
            [value]="group.id">{{group.bitbucket_group}}
            </mat-option>
           </mat-select> 
   </mat-form-field>
```

This is `ngOnInit` function:

```
selectedGroups = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    this.EditteamForm = this._fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        description: ''
    });
    let url = this.baseUrl + `/teams/${this.id}`;
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe((data: Array<any>) => {
        this.EditteamForm.controls['name'].setValue(data['results'][0]['name']);
        this.EditteamForm.controls['description'].setValue(data['results'][0]['description']);
        for (let i = 0; i < data['results'][0]['bitbucket_group'].length; i++) {
            let value = data['results'][0]['bitbucket_group'][i]['id'];
            this.selectedGroups.push(value);
        }

    });
}
```

What I do in `ngOnInit` is that I send an `HTTP request` to get the actual data of a team and show them in the form (prefilling the form) then let the user change them.
My problem is that, when I open the view that has the form, the value of selectedGroups is not getting selected in the mat-select field. Even that I have another component with the same logic and it works fine. Here I don't know what am I missing. 
When I do `console.log(this.selectedGroups)` I see that the list has a value, but it is not showing in `mat-select`.
Any clues?

Comment: try     [(ngModel)]="selectedGroups"

Comment: ngModel is deprecated in Angular 6 and I'm  using Reactive Forms so ngModel is not compatible. It gives this error: `ERROR Error: "
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive`

Comment: Could you post the output of your `console.log()`?

Comment: then where is formControl in the code

Comment: @Chellappan  I use formControl for simple inputs. For the select input I use [(value)]

Answer (score 2):

Use compareFn function that tells Angular how to compare the values.

> To customize the default option comparison algorithm, 
>   supports compareWith input. compareWith takes a function which has two
>   arguments: option1 and option2. If compareWith is given, Angular
>   selects option by the return value of the function

Ref:https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings"
  [compareWith]="compareFn" 
   [(value)]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ad3eqa-s3f4z1