# How can i make angular dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I wanted to show user details in the dropdown using the below objects.this was coming from api

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "abcd",
"place":"xyz",
"registrationid": 100
}
```

Getting user data from API based on name and email now I want to show this information in ui using dropdown.

Html

```html
<div fxFlex>
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select name="userVaraible" (selectionChange)="someMethod($event.value)" [(value)]="selectedUser" placeholder="User">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of getUserDetails()" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
      </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

user.component.ts

Here calling service and get the expected output from service and return a response to *ngfor also set a default value to dropdown

```js
selectedUser:string ;
getUserDetails(): string[]  {
        var response = this.userService.getUserDetails(this.CustomerDataSourceValue);
        
        if (response.length == 1)
        {
            selectedUser =response.toString();
            return response;
        }else{
            selectedUser =response[0].toString();
            return response;
        }
    }
```

user.service.ts

```js
getUserDetails(customerData: CustomerModel): string[] {
        var response = [];
        if ( customerData && customerData.id!= null customerData.registrationid != null) {

            if (customerData.registrationid != null && customerData.id != customerData.registrationid {

                    response.push(sprintf(this.resource.IdDisplayText, customerData.id, customerData.name, customerData.place))
                    response.push(sprintf(this.resource.IdDisplayText, customerData.registrationid, customerData.name, customerData.place))

                    return response


                } else {
                    response.push(sprintf(this.resource.IdDisplayText, customerData.id, customerData.name, customerData.place))
                }

            }
            return response;
        }
```

In this case, I can see two dropdown values based on my logic

```
1 - abcd - xyz
100 - abcd - xyz
```

and if response length one then no issues .if more than one then  i set first value to defult(1 - abcd - xyz) from array now if i select 2 (100 - abcd - xyz) from dropdown.its always set to ( 1 - abcd - xyz) .i am unable to change/select other values from drop-down. looks like its changing back to default value .how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the the problem because you didn't ask a question. Please ask a question and describe where you think the problem might be.

Comment: Possible solution here using [compareWith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724220/8062856).

Answer (score 0):

The question is not super clear but here's a try.

You can call your getUserDetails() in the ngOnInit() function of you component.ts and update the html template

user.component.ts

```
public selectedUsers: string[] = []; 

ngOnInit() { 
  this.selectedUsers = this.userService.getUserDetails();
}
```

user.component.htm

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of selectedUsers" [value]="item">
```

Comment: Cannot usein the ngoninit() because the value im getting based on user email and phnumber so my code should be this.userService.getUserDetails(this.CustomerDataSourceValue)

Answer (score 0):

> if response length one then no issues .if more than one then i set first value to defult(1 - abcd - xyz) from array

You don't need to check if the length is one vs. length more than one. All you need to do is to set the default value to the first one if the length is 1 or more. The thing you need to worry about is when the length is zero. How do you want to deal with it? Set to nothing? Set to some value? It's up to you.

> now if i select 2 (100 - abcd - xyz) from dropdown.its always set to ( 1 - abcd - xyz) .i am unable to change/select other values from drop-down. looks like its changing back to default value .how can i resolve this issue?

1.Do you mean you `selectedUser` variable in the `user.service.ts` that reverts back to the default value?

OR

2.Do you mean that the UI reverts back to the first selection after you click the value to select it?

If it's the #1, then you will need to use `ngModel` which do a 2-way binding.

Either way, I made a quick [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-45de56) here.

Comment: when I select a value from the dropdown I see the changes and when it set I see the default value. also, I am getting responses from API based on email and phone number so I cannot use it inside ngonint.ngOnInit() { 
  this.selectedUsers = this.userService.getUserDetails();
}

Comment: @itsme 
"`when I select a value from the dropdown I see the changes and when it set I see the default value.`"

Do you mean the `selectedUser` variable in the demo? 

"`I am getting responses from API based on email and phone number so I cannot use it inside ngOnInit.`"

The demo was to simplify things so you can get the point. I updated the demo to show you how to use `observable.`

Answer (score 0):

You have bound the whole object as a value, you can use id for value and name for option display text. This may help you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lr4uwp